# Wavelets and cryptography

Tags: wavelet

What papers/articles/books are considered good for getting started with wavelets' application to cryptography? I'm primarily interested in irregular grid wavelets, but regular grid will do for starters. What I'm definitely not interested at is steganography.

I'm posting this question here instead of [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) because them people [don't really talk](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=wavelets) about [wavelets](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=wavelet).

A (not nearly full) list of things I've taken a look at or stumbled upon:

- Fekri, Delgosha "Finite-field Wavelets with Applications in Cryptography and Coding" - don't have the actual book. Should I obtain it or just google its [table of contents](http://www.ablongman.com/preface/0130600202.pdf) apart?
- [Luo, "A novel symmetric cryptography based on the hybrid Haar wavelets encoder and chaotic masking scheme"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1021333)
- [Chan, "A block cipher cryptosystem usig wavelet transforms over finite fields"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1337276)
- [Kumar, Chokhandre, Mishra "Discrete wavelet transform based signal stegnography & encryption"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1aivQ8EXK-I7RsO0OiWOS_bORn8MswX_0BBk41OGQP2wNMtt5jFpNzt9o6agc/edit)
- [Manikandan, Kamarasan, Sairam, "A New Approach for Secure Data Transfer based on Wavelet Transform"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1DaSIjATpNsPdPpDdawqK4xYNXOAyHo4sucAnNRoYE-q04j_unxeydmIbcKOK/edit)

(Basically I was searching on google and google scholar for various combinations of "cryptography", "wavelets", "DWT", etc)

Comment: Did you try finding something? Google scholar: "criptography, wavelets". Tell us what you tried (and _why_), and then we can try telling you what you missed.

Comment: Added a few bits from my search history. See update post.

Comment: I think the question should be phrased as what are the most common wavelets criptography algorithms employed and in what papers are this depicted and if there are any benchmark papers. This question may be of interest and should be edited